# Azure app registration throws ERROR: Request contains a property with duplicate values

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, azure-cli

I am trying to add multiple *resourceAccesses* to an azure app while creating. When I try to add one scope the deployment getting succeeded, but while trying to add multiple scopes it throws an error like this

> ERROR: Request contains a property with duplicate values.
>
> Failed Azure CLI Command: az ad app create --display-name MytestApp
> --native-app false --required-resource-accesses 'C:\Users\AzDevOps\AppData\Local\Temp<somefilename>.hwd' --reply-

By creating the permission object like this ,

```
    $Aad = New-Object -TypeName "Microsoft.Open.AzureAD.Model.RequiredResourceAccess"
    $Aad.ResourceAppId = $msGraphPrincipal.AppId
    $delPermission1 = New-Object -TypeName "Microsoft.Open.AzureAD.Model.ResourceAccess" -ArgumentList "37f7f235-527c-4136-accd-4a02d197296e", "Scope"
    $delPermission2 = New-Object -TypeName "Microsoft.Open.AzureAD.Model.ResourceAccess" -ArgumentList "64a6cdd6-aab1-4aaf-94b8-3cc8405e90d0", "Scope"
    $delPermission3 = New-Object -TypeName "Microsoft.Open.AzureAD.Model.ResourceAccess" -ArgumentList "7427e0e9-2fba-42fe-b0c0-848c9e6a8182", "Scope"
    $delPermission4 = New-Object -TypeName "Microsoft.Open.AzureAD.Model.ResourceAccess" -ArgumentList "14dad69e-099b-42c9-810b-d002981feec1", "Scope"
    $delPermission5 = New-Object -TypeName "Microsoft.Open.AzureAD.Model.ResourceAccess" -ArgumentList "e1fe6dd8-ba31-4d61-89e7-88639da4683d", "Scope"

    $Aad.ResourceAccess = $delPermission1, $delPermission2, $delPermission3, $delPermission4, $delPermission5
```

I will save this object in a JSon file. After that using this

```
az ad app create <req codes> --required-resource-accesses <scopes from Json file>
```

command , I am trying to add the resorceAccesses in the app create command.
Did I miss anything or is there any other command to follow for adding multiple scopes?

Additional info : The graph version is v1

Edit the Json file data would be like :

```
[
    {
        "resourceAccess":  [
                               {
                                   "additionalProperties":  null,
                                   "id":  "37f7f235-527c-4136-accd-4a02d197296e",
                                   "type":  "Scope"
                               }
                           ],
        "resourceAppId":  "00"
    },
    {
        "resourceAccess":  [
                               {
                                   "additionalProperties":  null,
                                   "id":  "64a6cdd6-aab1-4aaf-94b8-3cc8405e90d0",
                                   "type":  "Scope"
                               }
                           ],
        "resourceAppId":  "00"
    },
    {
        "resourceAccess":  [
                               {
                                   "additionalProperties":  null,
                                   "id":  "7427e0e9-2fba-42fe-b0c0-848c9e6a8182",
                                   "type":  "Scope"
                               }
                           ],
        "resourceAppId":  "00"
    },
    {
        "resourceAccess":  [
                               {
                                   "additionalProperties":  null,
                                   "id":  "14dad69e-099b-42c9-810b-d002981feec1",
                                   "type":  "Scope"
                               }
                           ],
        "resourceAppId":  "00"
    },
    {
        "resourceAccess":  [
                               {
                                   "additionalProperties":  null,
                                   "id":  "e1fe6dd8-ba31-4d61-89e7-88639da4683d",
                                   "type":  "Scope"
                               }
                           ],
        "resourceAppId":  "00"
    }
]
```

Comment: "I will save this object in a JSon file" - have you taken a look at the resulting file? Does the contents look like you expect?

Comment: yes exactly the same. And no duplicate values

Comment: Can you post the json you are using? You posted the code you use to generate the json but the question is actually related to the az (command line) tool, at the moment the PS code is irrelevant without showing the generated json

Comment: The structure of the json seems incorrect for this, you should only have one "resourceAccess" node per resourceApp, under the resourceaccess (array) you should list ALL permissions required for that resource.

Comment: ok I will correct that and see

Comment: An easy way to compare the structure of your json with a valid one: do a manual app reg, set the permissions, then download the manifest file. The manifest will also contain the requiredressourceaccess node in the json (with the correct structure)

Comment: Thanks @bluuf  and @ Mathias , I have modified the logic behind creating the Json. Now am able to add multiple scopes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Bluuf and Mathias mentioned the issue was with my JSon file.

Based on this comment by Bluuf :

> The structure of the json seems incorrect for this, you should only
> have one "resourceAccess" node per resourceApp, under the
> resourceaccess (array) you should list ALL permissions required for
> that resource.

I have re-written the logic for creating the Json file.
After changing the logic the Json file has the value similar like this.

```
[
    {
        "resourceAccess":  [
                               {
                                   "additionalProperties":  null,
                                   "id":  "37f7f235-527c-4136-accd-4a02d197296e",
                                   "type":  "Scope"
                               },
                               {
                                   "additionalProperties":  null,
                                   "id":  "e1fe6dd8-ba31-4d61-89e7-88639da4683d",
                                   "type":  "Scope"
                               },
                               {
                                   "additionalProperties":  null,
                                   "id":  "14dad69e-099b-42c9-810b-d002981feec1",
                                   "type":  "Scope"
                               }
                           ],
        "resourceAppId":  "00"
    }
]
```

After this change I am able to add multiple scopes to the Azure App.